# Replicating to Older Versions of MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

According to an old [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (from the SQL Server 2008 R2 era), Microsoft SQL Server transactional replication subscribers need to be within two versions of the publisher. Does this hold true for more recent versions (i.e. 2012 & 2014)?

I've been unable to find current recent documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this still holds true.  It is covered in [Upgrade Replicated Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143699.aspx) in the SQL Server 2014 documentation.